# SQL Injection with backslash

Tags: sql, function, code-injection, backslash

This is sample code:

```
include("db_connect.php");
//
function foo($string){
    $s_array = array("'", '"');
    $result = str_replace($s_array, "\\", $string);
    return $result;
}
//
$first_var = $_POST['first_var'];
$second_var = intval($_POST['second_var']);
//
$first_var_result = foo($first_var);
//
mysql_query("UPDATE some_table SET first_column='".$first_var_result."', second_column='".$second_var."'  WHERE id='id'");
```

When $_POST['first_var'] equals ', **foo** function replaces **'** with \ and mysql returns ERROR.
**This is not my code**. I'm simpe interested in if this code is vulnerable (SQL Injection)? Thanks.

Comment: mysqli_escape_string use this method to avoid sql injection

Comment: Have a look [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12859942/why-shouldnt-i-use-mysql-functions-in-php), so you can write safer code.

Comment: Thank you for reply. But i dont want to avoid sql injection. This is not my code. I'm interested in, if this code is vulnerable.

Comment: I'm web developer and i know how to avoid SQL injection with (mysql_real_escape_string, addslashes, htmlspecialchars or any custom functions). This is not what i want.

Comment: “i know how to avoid SQL injection with (mysql_real_escape_string, addslashes, htmlspecialchars or any custom functions)” – No, apparently you don’t. Neither `addslashes`, nor `htmlspecialchars` and probably “any custom functions” either are appropriate for preventing SQL injections. You should be using parameterized statements as provided by prepared statements only!

Comment: I know about addslashes() vulnerability ("0xbf27 "). And as i said i know how to prevent SQL injection. And there are much more methods to prevent SQL injection  with custom function(s).

Answer (score 0):

Not this one but you are very close. If `first_var_result` ends with `'` or `"`, the replacement `\` will escape the apostrophe in the SQL query and `second_var` would be executed as code. If you would escape it with `foo` as well, you have SQL injection.

Comment: Thank you for fast reply. But second var is INT only.

Comment: It is now, it may not be in a year and nobody would notice this injection.

Comment: This SQL code is actually invalid, it misses `'` after `$second_var`.

Comment: Thank you very much for ur attention, i have already UPDATED code.